# Insert new row and copy the formulas from the row above at a selected location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains 3 tables(let's say each are 5 rows by 5 columns).

When I need to add a new row to one of the tables I just copy the last row from that table below(so I can have the formulas in the new row as well) and then re-edit it with the new values.

I would like however to have an easier solution for doing this. I want to select a row and then run a script. The script will copy the selected row below and initialize all cells with empty values.

I have googled around but I found nothing that could help me :(. I have found some scripts that are supposed to copy the last row and carry the formulas such as this one:

```
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

I wanted to start from that one and then try to modify the script to do what I want. However, I was not able to do so. When I create a new script and paste that code the script becomes 'unrunnable' :(. I understand that onOpen() is something called a 'trigger' which is some sort of reserved function name(or something like that). Does that have something to do with my script being unrunnable? 
Please explain how can I get that copied script to run like a normal script and also give me any tips in achieving what I want(adding a row with the formulas from the row above at a specific location).

Comment: The script you show works for me.  What's "unrunnable" about it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by this: `I would like however to have an easier solution for doing this. I want to select a row and then run a script. The script will copy the selected row below and initialize all cells with empty values.` what cell cells need to be initialized to zero?  Perhaps a copy of the spreadsheet would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For now since you just want to update the functionality don't worry about the onOpen and the menu just run addRow().

I rewrote it a little bit like so:

```
function addRow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(lr,1,1,lc);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lr, 1);
  rg.copyTo(sh.getRange(lr+1,1,1,lc), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

So now you have everything you need to get addRow to work.  From there we can discuss further what you would like to change.

This version uses the selected row instead of the last row.

```
function addRow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sh.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(lr,1,1,lc);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lr, 1);
  rg.copyTo(sh.getRange(lr+1,1,1,lc), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I have used the first function you provided that copies the last row and it is perfect for me. I have decided to combine all the spreadsheets into one spreadsheet and that's why I no longer(for now at least) need to copy the row at a specific location. I have also inserted an image and assigned that script to it so I have like a button that does this which is wonderful. However there is one little problem. The new image is not clickable on the android Sheets app :(.. It works fine on my PC but when I'm on my phone I can't click it. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hello @Cantaff0rd, there is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124307440) which causes Sheets App buttons to not work in smartphones.

Comment: Thanks. I will see what I can do about that. One more question. If I have a period trigger that says sends some emails and I schedule that to run every day will it run every day even if in one day I don't open the document at all?